# How to paint on video?

Tags: animation, effects

[image: animation on film]

Is there a specific name for this technique? so I can search for tutorials about it.

Comment: Don't know the name if there is one. I'd suggest to load the clip into photoshop, because you've got **most control about the brush** settings. Alternatively **blenders new grease pencil** is fun to play with: https://vimeo.com/113610809.

Comment: I want to achieve that kind of animation that the 2D objects are "on" the video. Take an animated character on the shoulder of an actor (so it moves with movements of the actor). After Effects can do this (really time consuming in Photoshop), but I don't know what I have to look for.

Comment: I understand what you mean, will write some instructions as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

The technique is classically called [rotoscoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotoscoping) after the original process done using projected film. If you google ***rotoscoping in after effects*** you should find lots of samples and tutorials.